# removing the session object which is already removed

Tags: java, session

I have a very simple query. Lets say a session object is not there or it is removed and i am using sessionMap.remove(non_existing_object_key or already_removed_object). Then what will happen? Will it throw exception?

Comment: you can check https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/SessionMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the code of SessionMap

> Removes the specified session attribute.

**Parameters:**
key the name of the attribute to remove.

**Returns:**
the value that was removed or null if the value was not found (and hence, not removed).

```
public V More ...remove(Object key) {
  if (session == null) {
   return null;
    }

synchronized (session) {
    entries = null;

   V value = get(key);
  session.removeAttribute(key.toString());

    return value;
 }
}
```

but in one line of remove method it is calling **HttpSession** method `removeAttribute(String key)` as:

```
session.removeAttribute(key.toString());
```

> this will throw **IllegalStateException** if it is called on an
>   invalidated session.